# C# Serial Port Conditional & Partial Reading

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am stumped. Searched myself blue in the face - no go.

I am trying to establish serial comms with a device that sends 2 different blocks of data (one after the other) every 1 second continuously. The first block starts with "PID" and the second block ends with "H18".

I only need to read once every 5 seconds.

My problem is two fold:

1. I have no idea/control when the read starts and often starts mid - block.
2. I have no control over the start and end cycle to ensure I get a full two blocks as I need both.

Both blocks are about 200 characters long in total, has no /r at the beginning and has /r/n in between various items.

I have tried doing two subsequent reads but no success. Tried playing with StartsWith and EndsWith but they are not recognized? The code has been all over the show, but here is the base I am working from currently:

```
static void DataReceivedHandlerbat(object sender,     SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var batm = sender as SerialPort;
        if ((batm != null) && (!_gotResponse))
        {
         while (stringb.Length < 200)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[batm.BytesToRead];
                int numRead = batm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                stringb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));

               // if (stringb.S  == 0)
                //{
                  //   _gotResponse = true;
                    // break;
                //}
              }
         }
    }
```

and

```
 /// Obtain Battery string

            SerialPort batm = new SerialPort();
            batm.PortName = "com4";
            batm.BaudRate = 19200;
            batm.DataBits = 8;
            batm.Parity = Parity.None;
            batm.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            batm.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandlerbat);

            batm.Open();

            //batm.ReadExisting();

            int timeoutMsb;
            timeoutMsb = 1000;

            var startTimeb = DateTime.Now;
            while (!_gotResponse && ((DateTime.Now - startTimeb).TotalMilliseconds < timeoutMsb))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            batm.Close();

            _gotResponse = false;

            //Build Battery String

            String bat = stringb.ToString();
```

Please help me - I am fairly new to C# and have struggled for 4 days with this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a GUI application or a background service?  Either way, ditch `DataReceived` event and use `ReadAsync`, as I showed [in my blog post](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport).  Then, buffer all incoming data into a `List<byte>` (this easily deals with messages which arrive split into two), and implement some synchronization logic.

Here's an outline of how synchronization works:

1. loop through the `List<byte>`, find the beginning of a message
2. determine whether the entire message has been received
3. copy the message payload and fire off an event so the business logic that acts on the message can be separate from the buffering/parsing logic
4. remove bytes from the list up to the end of the detected message
5. search the remainder of the buffer for more valid messages (repeat 1-4)
6. when the buffer `List<byte>` doesn't contain a complete message, call `ReadAsync` again

Comment: Hi Ben, Your blog post was actually something I came across in my search before I even posted here. Your answer makes perfect sense, but alas for a dummy like me it is really hard to replicate/code. Might I be so bold as to ask for some code assistance? This is a GUI app reading the data as described above, displaying it on win form after breaking it down into list and parsing data and finally posting to SQL db.

Comment: @edmundp: Just build it up in steps.  First, make an `async` function that loops calling `await sport.BaseStream.ReadAsync()` and each time you get data, write it to the debug console.  Be sure to use the number of bytes actually read, returned from `ReadAsync`, and not the full array size!  Then, add buffering to a `List<byte>` and print the buffer size to the debug console.  After that, start looking for `\r\n` sequences, pull the message ahead of that into an array (List's `CopyTo` is helpful), print it to the debug console, and use `RemoveRange` to take it out of the buffer.